# Render only changing part in the animation

Tags: rendering, animation

Is it possible to speed up rendering animations by telling Blender, where the changes occur?
Example: I have a chess board, and first, let's say, 40 frames is for one pawn moving, and the camera still. Therefore it's not needed, that the whole scene renders for every frame. All the frames are similar, they differ only in the proximity of the moving pawn. Is it possible to tell Blender: "render only this area of the image for every frame, and leave all the other things still, so render them only once". I'm sure it would greatly speed up the whole process.
Thanks in advance for the answer

Comment: I suspect newer version of blender (beta 3.0.* with xcycle support) is capable of better managing animations and render time when not all the image changes frame from frame. Give it a try

Answer (score 0):

Lets say it depends on the level of detail and realism you want. Mostly it has to do with the lighting and shadows. If you don't mind if the shadows aren't animated, then you can easily render just the static objects on to a transparent background, as a simple image. Then you can render out the dynamic parts onto a transparent background, then use the compositor and put it all together as the animation. If you want the dynamic shadows then it can be done as render layers, but the shadows will effect the chessboard and require it to be rendered. UV mapping and baking the materials will help with the render time. you will just want the diffuse color, none of the lighting or other effects. That will only help if the materials and textures are complex.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have made it another way - I rendered move by move, selecting a border for the direct proximity of the moving piece. Now I just need to figure out, how to glue the images together, so that a border becomes transparent